# How can two HTML template elements be updated using (HTMX)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, htmx

I have a form in which there are three fields, basically these fields contain drop-down lists - selections. These select lists are based on a data model that has fields associated with ForeynKey .

After completing this form.

I update information, code and do calculations in code.
Further after the calculations.
I am updating two elements on the template - a table and a graph.
I have these two elements in separate parts of the template.
Like two different pieces of HTML .
With (HTMX) I can only update one element on the table - this element is a chunk of the HTML template - which is updated by rendering that chunk of that template. How can I update another piece of the template?

How can two HTML template elements be updated using (HTMX) ?

I would be very grateful for any help.

--

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-6">
         <form method="POST" class="post-form">
             {% csrf_token %} {{form_1.as_p}}
             <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-light">Form</button>
         </form>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
         {{ div_1|safe }}
 
         {{ script_1|safe }}
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
         {{ div_2|safe }}
 
         {{ script_2|safe }}
     </div>
 </div>
```

--

```
 class Form_1(forms.ModelForm):
 
     class Meta:
         model = Model_1
         fields = "__all__"
```

--

```
 class Model_1(models.Model):
     name_1 = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Name_1")
     name_2 = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Name_2")
 
     def __str__(self):
         return self.name_1, self.name_2
```

--

```
 def form_1(request):
     context = {}
     form = Form_1(request.POST or None)
     if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
         script_1, div_1 = components(data_table)
     
         context['script_1'] = script_1
         context['div_1'] = div_1
         script_2, div_2 = components(fig)
     
         context['script_2'] = script_2
         context['div_2'] = div_2
 
         return render(request, "data_table", "fig", context)
 
     context['form_1'] = form
     return render(request, "form_1.html", context)
```

---

### added

```
def index_htmx(request):
    context = {}
    ///code///

    if request.htmx:
        print("HTMX")
        return render(request, 'index_htmx_added.html', context)

    return render(request, "index_htmx.html", context)
```

---

### index_htmx_added.html

```
    <div id="table"
         hx-swap="beforeend"
         hx-swap-oob="true"
         class="col-6">
        {{ div|safe }}
        {{ script|safe }}
    </div>

    <div id="figure" 
         hx-swap="beforeend"
         hx-swap-oob="true"
         class="col-6">
        {{ div_2|safe }}
        {{ script_2|safe }}
    </div>
```

---

### index_htmx.html

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
                <select
                        id="select-name"
                        class="custom-select"
                        name="select"
                        autocomplete="off"
                        hx-get="{% url 'index_htmx' %}"
                        hx-target="#figure, #table"">
                    {% for select in selector %}
                        <option value="{{ select }}">{{ select }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="table" class="col-6">
            {{ div|safe }}
            {{ script|safe }}
        </div>
        <div id="figure" class="col-6">
            {{ div_2|safe }}
            {{ script_2|safe }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

HTMX call this feature [Out of Band Swap](https://htmx.org/docs/#oob_swaps). In the response HTML you can have multiple HTML fragments with different targets and HTMX will swap the corresponding element on the page. Given your page looks like this:

```
<div id="tabular_data">...Tabular data...<div>
<div id="graph">...Graph...</div>
```

The response HTML should contain this (note the added `hx-swap-oob="true"`):

```
<div id="tabular_data" hx-swap-oob="true">...New tabular data...<div>
<div id="graph" hx-swap-oob="true">...New graph...</div>
```

HTMX will find `id="tabular_data"` element and swaps its content with the new content then do the same with `id="graph"` element.

These oob elements must be in the top level of the response, and not a children of an element.

At the backend you need to create a new template that contains all the element you want to swap together or just join the rendered HTML fragments when you return the response.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
You are saving me.

I have two elements.
I placed them, not as an embedding, (include) in the template from an additional other piece (part) of the html element.
And as part of the main part of the entire html template.

I end up returning elements from a piece of the html part.
Which contains two elements that I want to update.

If you have the opportunity, you can roughly suggest what you need to write in the settings of the div element.

I edited the main part of the question at the top - added new elements.

Maybe I have an error somewhere.

Comment: If you want to replace the original divs then you need to use `hx-swap="outerHTML"`, so the whole `<div id="table">...</div>` will be replaced with the new div from the response. The `beforeend` will append the new content to the container's bottom.

Comment: Surprisingly, it all worked out.
Thanks a lot.
It's some sort of magic.
I wanted to ask if it is possible to somehow add a simple spinner (loading) effect to the page or some part of the element objects?
So that when changing the HTMX transforms, there is something similar to a spinner for two seconds, whether it be part of the template or the entire template behind the smoke for two seconds in which something happens?

Comment: Yes, HTMX supports [loading indicators](https://htmx.org/docs/#indicators). During the request HTMX will add the `htmx-request` CSS class to the respective elements, so you can use some CSS rules e.g. to fade out the container element. Since you use OOB swaps with multiple targets, you can use the [`hx-indicator`](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-indicator/) attribute to specify the common parent element (e.g. `<div class="row">`) that you want to fade out during the request.